# How can you add two lines of text on a single line in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2010

Odd title, wasn't sure how to word it.  Basically, I have two separate fonts I want to be on the same line, for resume purposes.  My name is in a large font at the top, and I want my email and website address right-aligned directly beside it, one on top of the other.  However, I want the email and website to combine to the same height as my name.

[image: Title and email]

Is this even possible with Word?  Surely it is.  Here is an awesome graphic of what I'm hoping for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [table](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-format-a-table-in-word-2010.html) to get the layout you are looking for.  Create a table with 1 row and 2 columns.  Then split the right column into 2 rows.  Insert text as needed and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I'd also add to remove the borders. i.e. Rightclick, Borders and Shading, None, OK.